# Remote Deployment in Websphere 8.5 ND

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have WAS 8.5 installed on linux machine. I am building EAR file on windows machine and wanted to deploy it remotely on the linux machine from my build machine. Is is necessary to install websphere on my build machine to perform remote deployment on linux machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you need is the `WAS client`. 
Simple administrative script will help you install ear. Connect to your remote `WAS` using `wasadmin` and execute created script.

Details for the script you can find in [WAS documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_callappinstall.html).